# Create Table Type vs Create Type

Tags: sql, create-table, hana

[image]

Could anyone please describe in simple words about the two statements in this picture ? Your answer would be truly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about mysql, not oracle?

Comment: No I am not sure. This just cameby when I was looking on SQLscripts video.

Comment: I see, it's just your tags were a bit misleading

Comment: I misread your example. What RDBMS is this actually for? `CREATE TABLE TYPE xyz(publisher int)` is not valid TSQL.

Comment: This I found in a video tutorial for "SAP HANA database". But I am sure this is not specific but generic SQL statement. Just that I dont understand the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using HANA, it's SQLScript, so:

`CREATE TABLE TYPE` is a deprecated syntax for registering table types.

`CREATE TYPE` is a new syntax for defining table types. As already mentioned, table types do not have an instance, it's like a template for future use.

As for the table in the picture, I think it was given to specify differences in an old and new syntax in a nice way.